# Is adjuvent chemotherapy permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, medical, health

I have had surgery to remove breast cancer. My oncologist has advised chemotherapy for next stage treatment. She states that although surgery has removed the cancer, this is to mop up any stray cells that might be left behind. Benefits of chemo are 6% for disease free survival but there are many potential and permanent side effects to this. What is the Islamic standpoint on such treatment?